# Scroll back to last command prompt in termite

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, oh-my-zsh

I often execute commands in the terminal that print a lot of information in the terminal.

Is there a key combination to jump back in the terminal to the line, in which the last executed command is written, so I can see that start of the output?

I am using termite and zshell currently. Is there a different terminal with this feature?

Answer (score 2):

The default linux terminal can do it. Inside your Terminal Window, go to `Edit` and `Profile Preferences`. In the `Scrolling` tab check the `Unlimited` checkbox.

It's also possible to store the commande result in a file to consult it :

```
"your_commands" > commands_output.txt
```

**EDIT :**

To see the start of output you have multiple choice :

1. You can pipe the output with `less` or `more` like :

   `command | more`
2. Use the [history expension](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) with your last command :

   `!! | more`
3. Use a terminal like terminator which allow searching through the scroll back. Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> to show the search bar. GIF for exemple :

[image: Q469788 on AskUbuntu]

Comment: Which terminal do you mean with `default terminal`?
My problem is not that the terminal buffer is not big enough, I just don't want to scroll up all the time, but jump directly to the last entered command.

Comment: Oh... Sorry a misunderstand what you ask for. I will edit my post in a minute !